# Qual o suporte nativo do Python para manipulação de banco de dados?

Tags: python, banco-de-dados

Encontrei coisas a respeito de um módulo chamado mysqldb, mas não encontrei documentação disponível no [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org)

*Por favor, desconsiderar responder com frameworks, como Django.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Defina nativo. Se está falando da biblioteca padrão [só o SQLite está disponível](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3).

Se está falando de módulos extras disponíveis para acesso direto na API mais crua possível do banco de dados aí tem uma [lista não definitiva na Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DatabaseInterfaces):

- [IBM DB2](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DB2)
- [Firebird](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Firebird) (e Interbase)
- [Informix](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Informix)
- [Ingres](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Ingres)
- [MySQL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/MySQL)
- [Oracle](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Oracle)
- [PostgreSQL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PostgreSQL)
- [SAP DB](https://wiki.python.org/moin/SAP%20DB) (MaxDB)
- Microsoft [SQL Server](https://wiki.python.org/moin/SQL%20Server)
- Microsoft [Access](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Microsoft%20Access)
- [Sybase](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Sybase)

Note a existência de mais de uma opção.

Existem opções não relacionais e até o que chamam de nativo que me parece ser bancos desenvolvidos em Python exclusivamente para uso com a linguagem.

Particularmente sou como o AP, prefiro o suporte mais básico, qualquer abstração extra, como o *framework* SQLAlchemy, eu prefiro não usar a não ser que o problema peça mesmo por ele, o que é raro tecnicamente, em geral isso é decisão "política".

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

Na minha opinião, em linguagens que suportam o paradigma OO, é muito mais produtivo utilizar um ORM (quando disponível) para acesso a bancos relacionais. No caso do python, se não estou usando um Framework que utiliza seu próprio ORM, como o Django, por exemplo (inclusive, lamento o Django não ter eleito o SQLAlchemy como ORM oficial), eu sempre opto pelo 
[sqlalchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/).

[SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/), é, para mim, o "suporte nativo" de acesso a bancos relacionais no python (claro que estou exagerando para enfatizar a importancia do toolkit).

Veja, na página do projeto, quem usa SQLAlchemy: Yelp, The open Stack Project, Reddit, Mozilla, Dropobx, Fedora, Freshbook, e... [por ai vai.](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/organizations.html)

Dialetos suportados (no core):

- Firebird
- Microsoft SQL Server
- MySQL
- Oracle
- PostgreSQL
- SQLite
- Sybase

Dialetos suportados por terceiros:

- ibm_db_sa - driver for IBM DB2 and Informix, developed jointly by IBM and SQLAlchemy developers.
- sqlalchemy-redshift - driver for Amazon Redshift, adapts the existing PostgreSQL/psycopg2 driver.
- sqlalchemy_exasol - driver for EXASolution.
- sqlalchemy-sqlany - driver for SAP Sybase SQL Anywhere, developed by SAP.
- sqlalchemy-monetdb - driver for MonetDB.
- snowflake-sqlalchemy - driver for Snowflake.
- sqlalchemy-tds - driver for MS-SQL, on top of pythone-tds.
- crate - driver for CrateDB.

Comment: Interessante. Obrigado. ps: por nativo, eu quis dizer que já vem com a linguagem (built-in), no core da linguagem. No caso do python, seria um módulo. Valeu!